# Drupal 8 Libraries - CSS in head - JS in body

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'm slowly understanding the concept of Durpal 8's Libraries.

How would I add a library's CSS to the head of the document, while adding a library's JS to just before the closing body tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the standard process of adding the libraries in Drupal 8, you should achieve this by default.

Please check this link for details 
[adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme)